# How to know the user login

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.Net and SQL Server 2005

I have a login page in Windows based application,  Once login, in the next page the user name should display in the menu.

For Example,

```
In a Admin Login, the Admin should display in the MDI From menu
In a User Login, the User name should display in the MDI From menu
...
```

Need VB.Net Code Help

Comment: Please update the question title and tags. It's very misleading to know what the question is about. Also it's hard to help without any code provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that you have a table named `Login` and has three fields (`username`,`password`,`role`).

Pseudo code:

1. Fetch the role from the login table of  given `username and password`.
2. If result is null then say "good bye" and exit from the system.
3. If result is "Admin" then instantiate/show the Admin MDI.
4. If result is "User" then open/show User MDI form.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the name of the logged-in user?

```
User.Identity.Name
```